# How to Integrate MathJax with Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, mathjax

I'm getting template parsing errors while integrating MathJax into Ionic2 please help me with this,

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    .....
    "mathjax": "^2.7.0"
    },
```

home.ts

```
import mj from "mathjax";
```

home.html

```
<ion-card-title> Name </ion-card-title>
      <span> When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrtb^2-4ac \over 2a.}$$</span>
      <button (click)= render()> Render Katex</button>
      <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
          tex2jax: 'inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
        });
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" async src="../../../node_modules/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

Comment: how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mathjax

You need to install typescript declarations.
Try

```
npm install @types/mathjax --save
```

check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117407/how-could-i-import-types-three-in-angular2/41118120)

Comment: I did `typings install dt~mathjax --save --global`

Comment: which ia your ionic version? can you share package.json

Comment: `"@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "mathjax": "^2.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"`

Comment: typings is no longer used with RC3.. You will have to undo the steps and just directly set it up with npm @types

Comment: they moved all type declarations to npm

Comment: Thank you Suraj I will update you after using @types

Comment: getting Typescript Error
File '/Users/Ashutosh/Documents/ionic/m1/myApp/node_modules/@types/mathjax/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Comment: how are you importing it?

Comment: npm install @types/mathjax --save
can I  share my code(github)?

Comment: import * as mj from "mathjax";  tried this? sure ok

Comment: did you checked the repository?

Comment: yes.. You have installed only types without the mathjax package

Comment: then use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370826/how-to-get-mathjax-working-with-angular2

Comment: I have installed both types and npm package but couldnt render math equation coz they are not initialised as they mentioned in their docs e.g `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</body>`

Answer (score 0):

I have been googling "Integrating MathJax in ionic 3 offline" for last 2 days. All I found that is I have to use a directive to achieve that. But this approach is not fast for such an app which has lots of mathematical equation. So I came up with another solution:

1. download MathJax offline file from [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/archive/2.7.1.zip), extract and rename that with **MathJax** and place the whole folder in **www/assets** folder of your ionic app.
2. add the code given below in the head section of index.html file

   `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
     MathJax.Hub.Config({
       imageFont: null,
       extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
       jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
       tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
     });
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" async
             src="assets/MathJax/MathJax.js">
     </script>`
3. now for every page where you want to load mathematical equation, just paste the code below.

   `ionViewDidEnter() {
       eval('MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub])');
     }`

By doing these three steps you will have integrated MathJax successfully.

But the problem is the size of MathJax folder is so big. You can reduce the size up to 3mb by just having the following directories and files

- MathJax.js
- extensions
- fonts

  - HTML-CSS
  - TeX

    - eof
    - otf
    - svg
- jax

  - element
  - input

    - TeX
  - output

    - HTML-CSS
    - autoload
    - config.js
    - fonts

      - TeX
    - imageFonts.js
    - jax.js

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file, add following script...
`

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
     showProcessingMessages: false,
     tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Then make a directive for mathjax as follows

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';
declare var MathJax: {
    Hub: {
    Queue: (param: Object[]) => void
    }}   
            @Directive({selector: '[MathJax]'})
            export class MathJaxDirective {
                @Input('MathJax') MathJaxInput: string = "";
                constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
                }
                ngOnChanges() {
                   this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.MathJaxInput;
                  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.el.nativeElement]);
                }
            }
```

Then in app.module.ts
`import {MathJaxDirective} from "...` to use it in you entire app

For a condition if you have multiple modules then make a commonModule something like

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MathJaxDirective } from "./directives/MathJax.directive";    
@NgModule({
        declarations: [MathJaxDirective],
        exports: [MathJaxDirective]
    })
    export class CommonModule { }
```

and import this module in the required module

Now you are good to go

just in your .html
`<div [Mathjax]="sometxt">{{ sometxt }}</div>`

and in your .ts
`sometxt: string = "$$someLatex"`

Hope, this will help someone